# Download txt file from github

Tags: python, python-3.x, github, download, python-requests

I have an open txt file in Github, however, I've tried the whole StackOverflow for answers - and there are nothing that could help:

link to github:
https://github.com/netology-code/py-homework-basic-files/blob/master/3.2.http.requests/DE.txt

At the end, I've completed with:

```
import os.path

cwd=os.getcwd()

import requests
url = 'https://github.com/netology-code/py-homework-basic-files/blob/master/3.2.http.requests/DE.txt'
resp = requests.get(url)

filename='file'
filename = os.path.join(cwd,filename)
```

But there is no new file in directory of project, as well as I'm recieving a bunch of stuff that I don't need from asking to "resp" file, and I don't even know how to download the text of this file itself. Could somebody help, please?

Yes, I've just saw a link with file, it also could be use and I recieve exatcly what I want and I can use it:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/netology-code/py-homework-basic-files/master/3.2.http.requests/DE.txt

But, the problem of downloading still exists.

Comment: @Joe - no, unfortunately, it doesn't help. There is a complete empty code as result (as well if I'm trying to "print" variables in steps inside, and there is no creation of file at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that in code you use link starting with `github`, whilst link you describe as working properly starts with `raw.github`
Using second you could do:

```
import requests
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/netology-code/py-homework-basic-files/master/3.2.http.requests/DE.txt'
resp = requests.get(url)
with open('file.txt', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(resp.content)
```

This code will create `file.txt` in current working directory with downloaded content. Note that I use `'wb'` mode (*write binary*) and `resp.content` which is `bytes`. Response object has also `.text` which is `str`, but problems might arise due to character encoding in this case.

*(tested in Python 3.7.3 + requests 2.22.0)*

Comment: I get a `NameError: name 'resp' is not defined`

Comment: @Tropillo I fixed my code sample

Answer (score 3):

You never actually wrote the response to a file. All you did was concatenate the current working directory with the filename you wanted to write to.

To write a file in the current directory, you don’t need the OS module. Python has built-in support for file handling.

Also, the requests module `get` method returns metadata as well as text. You can extract the plain text in the object’s `text` variable. (Below: `res.text`)

```py
import requests as req

url = “https://github.com/netology-code/py-homework-basic-files/blob/master/3.2.http.requests/DE.txt”
res = req.get(url)

file = open(“filename.txt”, “w”)
file.write(res.text)
file.close()
```

`open(f, m)` searches the current directory for a file with name `f` and attempts to open it for reading `”r”` or writing `”w”`. If the mode is write and the file does not exist, Python will attempt to create it.

If you want to learn more about file I/O, I suggest following a guide on [w3schools.com](http://w3schools.com)